# Can i stop the "Public" schema from being Dropped with pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am doing a pg_dump command as follows:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username xxx --format plain --clean --inserts --verbose --file /Users/xxx/documents/output/SYSTEM_admin_20131203101809.sql --exclude-table public.dbmirror_mirroredtransaction --exclude-table public.dbmirror_mirrorhost --exclude-table public.dbmirror_pending --exclude-table public.dbmirror_pendingdata --exclude-table public.mdflog --exclude-table public.fcpersistentstore --exclude-table public.backup_restore --exclude-table public.mdflogeventcode testdb
```

The problem I have is that in the plain sql file that is created it adds a command to try and DROP the whole of the PUBLIC schema as shown in this snippet:

```
...
DROP FUNCTION public.f_updateeventlog();
DROP FUNCTION public.f_updateadmindata();
DROP PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DROP SCHEMA public;

CREATE SCHEMA public;
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';
...
```

I DO want to drop all the other objects I have not excluded in the exclude-tables parameters I have provided, but I DONT want it to DROP the schema.

I have tried adding the schema as an exclude-table parameter but that did not work.

I am using Postgresql 8.4 for the pg_dump.

EDIT: I wanted to update this question and say I believe that it is not possible to get pg_dump to exclude the DROP / CREATE public command in the plain format. I believe you have to use the custom format and then pg_restore in order to stop that from happening. As I am using psql to restore and pg_dump with plain format, I simply remove the commands I don't want from the sql file after its created automatically as part of the Java process I am creating and I can get around this. I am leaving the question in case someone does find a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to post-process the dump after it has been made.  You could do this with `grep` or the like or just search and delete from the dump after it has been made.

The fact is that you are using the `--clean` option which drops the restored database objects.  There isn't a ready way to tell pg_dump to drop only some restored database objects, which is probably a good thing.